# Confusion over the time taken by write() and read() sys calls

Tags: unix, time, system-calls, unix-timestamp

The below code simply calculates the time taken to write a file.

```
#include<time.h>
void main()
{
  int fp;
  long a,b;
  char *str = "Life is like that only";
  fp = open("tmp.txt",O_WRONLY,0666);
  time(&a);
  write(fp,str);
  time(&b);
 /*(b-a) should be the time taken to write
  * the file tmp.txt.
  */
  close(fp);
  return;
}
```

My question is that if we have a single CPU then whether the time taken (b-a) would be exact or it can be affected by the execution of other process running parallel.
Some posts here mention that write() and read() can be treated almost like atomic syscalls as if they are not successful EINTR is set that simply means to try again.But still does that mean if it is successful then in the course of its execution all other processes are on hold.

Answer (score 0):

Other processes (that are not using I/O or that are using I/O on different devices) can run while your process is waiting for the write to complete, and your process may not immediately get the CPU back after it completes.

In practice, for a small write to a regular file, your write() will probably return immediately after copying your data into a kernel-space buffer, rather than waiting for it to go all the way to the disk.

Comment: Amount of data is not my concern, it is the time if it can be a exact one or context-switching can make it erroneous.